# Copy rows from Sheet(Data) to Sheet(Result) based on values from Sheet(Items)(Excel 2016)

Tags: vba, excel

My coding skill is like zero,i would like if anyone can modifying this code or make a completely different code for me.

I use this code to copy rows from Sheet(Data) to Sheet(Result) based on value found in Sheet(Items)

```
Sub TestCopy()
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long

With Worksheets("Data")
LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
End With

MsgBox (LastRow)
With Worksheets("Result")
j = .Cells(.Rows.count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1
End With

For i = 1 To LastRow
With Worksheets("Data")
If .Cells(i, 3).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Items").Range("A1") Then
.Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Result").Range("A" & j)
j = j + 1
End If
End With
Next i
End Sub
```

But this only moves the rows with value found in cell "A1". 
What i need is to move rows based on value in A1,A2,A3.... until there is an empty cell.

Example:

Data sheet looks like this:

```
Sub Locator Item    On-Hand LPN Serial
ABC AA010101    445-0744166 1   PLK123456   XX45684
ABC AA010102    445-0719738 2   PLK123457   XX45685
ABC AA010103    000-0000000 3   PLK123458   XX45686
ABC AA010104    445-0719738 4   PLK123459   XX45687
ABC AA010105    000-0000000 5   PLK123460   XX45688
ABC AA010106    445-0719738 6   PLK123461   XX45689
ABC AA010107    000-0000000 7   PLK123462   XX45690
ABC AA010108    445-0719738 8   PLK123463   XX45691
ABC AA010109    000-0000000 9   PLK123464   XX45692
DEF BB010101    445-0744166 10  PLK123465   XX45693
DEF BB010102    2181-K090-V001  11  PLK123466   XX45694
DEF BB010103    2181-K090-V001  12  PLK123467   XX45695
DEF BB010104    000-0000000 13  PLK123468   XX45696
DEF BB010105    445-0744166 14  PLK123469   XX45697
DEF BB010106    000-0000000 15  PLK123470   XX45698
DEF BB010107    445-0720880 16  PLK123471   XX45699
DEF BB010108    2181-K090-V001  17  PLK123472   XX45700
DEF BB010109    000-0000000 18  PLK123473   XX45701
GHI CC010101    000-0000000 19  PLK123474   XX45702
GHI CC010102    2181-K090-V001  20  PLK123475   XX45703
GHI CC010103    000-0000000 21  PLK123476   XX45704
GHI CC010104    000-0000000 22  PLK123477   XX45705
GHI CC010105    445-0744166 23  PLK123478   XX45706
GHI CC010106    445-0720880 24  PLK123479   XX45707
GHI CC010107    000-0000000 25  PLK123480   XX45708
GHI CC010108    2181-K090-V001  26  PLK123481   XX45709
GHI CC010109    000-0000000 27  PLK123482   XX45710
JKL DD010101    445-0744166 28  PLK123483   XX45711
JKL DD010102    000-0000000 29  PLK123484   XX45712
JKL DD010103    000-0000000 30  PLK123485   XX45713
JKL DD010104    445-0720880 31  PLK123486   XX45714
JKL DD010105    445-0744166 32  PLK123487   XX45715
JKL DD010106    000-0000000 33  PLK123488   XX45716
JKL DD010107    445-0720880 34  PLK123489   XX45717
JKL DD010108    445-0744166 35  PLK123490   XX45718
JKL DD010109    000-0000000 36  PLK123491   XX45719
```

Items sheet looks like this:

```
445-0719738
2181-K090-V001
445-0744166
445-0720880
```

Comment: Would you consider using a filter on the **Data** (criteria from Items!A1:A4) and copying the filtered results across *en masse* ?

Comment: If that's something i can do with a script I'm okay with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [AutoFilter method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221844.aspx) can help you select the rows you are looking for and deliver them in one piece to the results worksheet.

```
Sub TestCopy_jpd()
    Dim v As Long, vITMs() As Variant, rng As Range
    With Worksheets("Items")
        With .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
            For Each rng In .Cells
                ReDim Preserve vITMs(v)
                vITMs(v) = rng.Value2
                v = v + 1
            Next rng
        End With
    End With
    With Worksheets("Data")
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            .AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:=vITMs, Operator:=xlFilterValues
            'step down one row off the header
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
                'are there rows to copy?
                If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then
                    'there are visiblke rows - copy and paste them
                    .Cells.Copy _
                        Destination:=Worksheets("Result").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                End If
            End With
        End With
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

The Items worksheet is examined first and an array of the items is constructed. This is used as the criteria in the [Range.AutoFilter Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx). A quick examination to see if there are visible cells to copy follows and if there are, the copy and paste operation is completes the operation.

Addendum:

To address your original question, you need to check if the *Item* in the Data worksheet matches any of the *Items* listed in the Items worksheet.

```
With Worksheets("Data")
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(.Cells(i, 3).Value, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Items").Columns(1), 0)) Then
            .Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Result").Range("A" & j)
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

Doing this row-by-row will be appreciably slower but I wanted to offer up the correct method of achieving your original goal.